# MockBean does not work with classes in Spring boot 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

This is  my setup:

- Spring boot 3.1
- JDK 17

I have this simple junit test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ATestClass {


    @MockBean private AuditService2 auditEventService2;

    @MockBean private AuthorizationManager authorizationManager;

    @Test
    void getEvents() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class AuditService2 {

    public int sumar(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

The framework (Spring) is not mocking AuditService2 which is a class. This is injecting the actual bean

The framework does mock AuthorizationManager

The only difference between two AuditService2 is a class , AuthorizationManager an interface

This used to work in Spring boot 2.X, what is the issue here ?

Comment: How did you verify that real implementation was injected? There were no significant changes in @MockBean behaviour in Spring Boot 3 that I know of, so your example looks correct and should work just fine.

Comment: I added a debug point

Comment: can you try to write your test in such a way that it tests AuditService2? i,e, put assertEquals(4, auditEventService2.sumar(2,2); in your test. I predict that it will fail as sumar will return null, as the object is mocked in reality. Then, you will be able to use Mockito.when to mock the behaviour of the sumar() method.

Answer (score 0):

You injected a mocked object using this code:

```
@MockBean private AuditService2 auditEventService2;
```

However, you can also alter a method behavior of the mocked object by utilizing Mockito when. Example:

```
when(auditEventService2.someMethod(any())).thenReturn("mocked result");
```

Try to change an output of some methods from mocked beans and check if actually works.